# excel cell coloring

Tags: c#, colors, cell

I am using c# to color particular cells of excel file.
i am using

```
Application excel = new Application();
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(destPath);
 Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];
ws.Cells[row, clmn].Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbBlack;
```

to color cells..But this is not working..
It is giving an exception on the last line where i am coloring the cells

```
"Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"
```

I am unable to fix the exception
Can anyone help me out..

Comment: Are you sure it's `wb.Worksheets[1]` and not `wb.Worksheets[0]` you're looking for? Excel by default numbers worksheets starting with 0. Also, does Cells[row, clmn] have any content? If not, you may have problems setting formatting; Excel often uses sparse array storage, meaning that a particular cell doesn't really exist until content is placed in it.

Answer (score 1):

It might not work because the worksheet is protected.

You can check it the following way:

```
Application excel = new Application();
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(destPath);
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];

bool wasProtected = ws.ProtectContents;
if (wasProtected == true)
{
    // unprotect the worksheet
}
else
{
    ws.Cells[row, clmn].Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbBlack;
}

...

if (wasProtected == true)
{
    // protect back the worksheet
}
```

Comment: You don't need to specify "== true", you just need to specify (wasProtected) or if you want to check for false (!wasProtected).  Just FYI for future reference as it saves time.

Answer (score 0):

In my previous project I used the following snippet to Color Cells in Excel:

```
ws.Cells[row, clmn].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color.Black);
```

Comment: No it's not working.. It is giving an exception "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

Comment: Check if row and clmn are greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code that you have on a new Excel file and it works fine.  However, I was able to reproduce the error when testing with a row value of 0.  So maybe the problem is with the row and clmn values.  Otherwise it must be something specific to your Excel file... maybe a protected cell or something along those lines.